# How do I intercept the global PASTE in Android? Want to process it first

Tags: android

In the Android environment, the user can long press in a text field, and then if there is something on the clipboard, can paste it. I want to write a system replacement that would always come to my code for me to inspect the text before the paste, no matter where. There's a converse for the copy command by using the Clipboard manager, but ideally, I'd like it so nothing has to be on the clipboard. Perhaps I am asking to be able to intercept a long press in a text field, again, at all times?

I'd also hope to pop up a menu if certain "commands" are intercepted.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly is the processing you want to do but maybe a workaround is to create a broadcast receiver for de copy action, preprocess the text and change it on the same clipboard before user pastes it. By this, the paste action will paste what you processed.

Here is a good tutorial that will show how to do this: https://code.google.com/p/my-clips/